# Не отображаются данные в таблице TableView

Tags: java, база-данных, oracle, javafx, intellij-idea

При запуске формы никаких ошибок не выводится, но метод getDoctors() в какой-то момент начинает работать с пустотой, и, думаю, поэтому таблица не заполняется, хотя запрос правильный.

FXML:

```
@FXML
private void initialize () {
    try {
        doct_id.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getDoctId().asObject());
        doc_name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getDoctName());
        doc_address.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getDoctAddress());
        doc_phone.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getDoctPhone());
        doc_salary.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getDoctSalary().asObject());
        System.out.println("everything is OK there ");
        ObservableList<Doctors> data = DbLogic.getDoctors();
        doct_table.setItems(data);
    } catch (SQLException  | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
```

SQL:

```
public static ObservableList<Doctors> getDoctors() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String sql = "select * from doctors";
    ResultSet rSet = null;
    try {
        rSet = DBUtil.dbExecute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("smth went wrong while get records from server "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    try {
        ObservableList<Doctors> doclist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        while (rSet.next()){
          int id = rSet.getInt("ID");
          String name = rSet.getString("NAME");
            String phone = rSet.getString("PHONE");
            String address = rSet.getString("ADDRESS");
            int salary = rSet.getInt("SALARY");
            System.out.println("id "+id+" "+name+" "+phone+""+salary+"");
            doclist.add(new Doctors(id, name,  phone, address, salary));
        }
        return doclist;
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("smth went wrong while load data from table "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

DBUtil:

```
public static ResultSet dbExecute (String sqlQuery) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try (CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet()) {

        try {
            dbConnect();
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            crs.populate(rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("smth went wrong in dbExecute! " + e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            dbDisconnect();
        }
        return crs;
    }
}
```

Doctors:

```
public class Doctors {

private IntegerProperty idProperty;
private StringProperty nameProperty;
private StringProperty phoneProperty;
private StringProperty addressProperty;
private IntegerProperty salaryProperty;

public Doctors (int id, String name, String phone, String address, int salary) {
    this.idProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    this.nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.phoneProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(phone);
    this.addressProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
    this.salaryProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(salary);

}

public int getDocId () {
    return idProperty.get();
}

public void setDocId(int id) {
    this.idProperty.set(id);
}

public IntegerProperty getDoctId() {
    return idProperty;
}

public String getDocName () {
    return nameProperty.get();
}

public void setDocName(String name) {
    this.nameProperty.set(name);
}

public StringProperty getDoctName() {
    return nameProperty;
}

public int getDocSalary () {
    return salaryProperty.get();
}

public void setDocSalary(int salary) {
    this.idProperty.set(salary);
}

public IntegerProperty getDoctSalary() {
    return salaryProperty;
}

public String getDocAddress () {
    return addressProperty.get();
}

public void setDocAddress(String address) {
    this.addressProperty.set(address);
}

public StringProperty getDoctAddress() {
    return addressProperty;
}
public String getDocPhone () {
    return phoneProperty.get();
}

public void setDocPhone(String phone) {
    this.phoneProperty.set(phone);
}

public StringProperty getDoctPhone() {
    return phoneProperty;
}
```

}

Comment: Геттеры свойств в классе `Doctors` следует заканчивать на `"Property"` — этот суффикс захардкоден в JavaFX. Например, `public IntegerProperty doctIdProperty() { return idProperty;}`

Comment: @oshatrk
так а у меня разве не написано { return idProperty;}?

Comment: А зачем вообще хранить данные в Property формате, если не предполагается использовать бинды? У вас данные уже в обсервабллисте, зачем их еще раз оборачивать в подобное.

Comment: что именно подразумевается под фразой "в какой-то момент начинает работать с пустотой"? метод возвращает пустой список? или список докторов всегда из базы подгружается корректно?

Comment: @GeorgeLu То замечание относилось к названиям методов, например, `doctIdProperty()`.